# Can different sources with same voltage output can drive different amount of current through the circuit

Tags: voltage, current

I started experimenting with electronic devices. While I was doing that I connected a DC motor to output of arduino which provides 5V. It could not provide enough amount of current. But when I connected the same motor to my phones battery which provides 3.8V output it provided a lot more current. So I was confused wasn't the current from arduino should be more as it has more voltage?

Comment: An Arduino's IO port can source an absolute maximum of 40mA, with a recommended maximum of just 25mA. It has absolutely nothing to do with the voltage.

Comment: Terms you want to study: _Ohm's law_, _Internal resistance_

Comment: source impedance ...

Comment: the "ON" resistance of the Atmega328P (microcontroller chip used in the Arduino Uno) output port drivers is pretty high, meaning it can only source so much current. Also experimenting like that is a sure way to blow shit up, make sure you know what you are doing/can guess what is going to happen first before doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the voltage and current requirements of your motor so some guessing is required to provide an answer.  Typically, small hobbyist type DC motors will draw at least 100 ma at 5 volts.  The Arduino output port cannot provide that much current. If you measure the port voltage with the motor connected it will be much less than 5 volts and not enough to turn the motor.  The battery, on the other hand, can provide sufficient current to power the motor without dropping much voltage. Basically you need to match a power source to a load in both voltage and current.  Because a source is rated to provide a given voltage, it will only do so if its rated current is not exceeded. You exceeded the current rating of the Arduino port.

Answer (score 0):

If you treat a motor as a resistance (which is mostly valid when it's in a steady state), then yes, a higher voltage should mean a higher current. However, that makes the assumption that the voltage source is ideal, and that's not true here.

A battery is a pretty good approximation of a voltage source, at least over short periods (the voltage will decrease as it charges), though batteries have internal resistance, meaning the voltage across its terminals also drops depending on current draw. You can measure this and model it as an ideal battery in series with a resistance.

A GPIO port on a microcontroller like the AVR on an Arduino is an even worse approximation of a constant voltage. While it will output 5v at 0 current, it has a limit on how much current it can sink or source. In the case of the AVR, this is 20mA. A typical electric motor will draw a lot more than this, which can have consequences ranging from the voltage on the IO pin dropping out (which is what's happening here) up to destroying the microcontroller!

If you want to drive a motor from a microcontroller, you probably want an [H-Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_bridge). There are prebuilt Arduino shields with H-Bridge drivers, like [Adafruit's motor driver shield](http://www.adafruit.com/product/81).